# iOS UITest error when try to select picker element

Tags: ios, swift, xcode8, xcode-ui-testing

I'm trying to select an element of picker, the picker has Accessibility = picker_station, why can I do ? is something wrong ? or I need to use other code.

```
let app = XCUIApplication()
app.pickers["picker_station"].pickerWheels.element.adjust(toPickerWheelValue: "Aberdeen")
```

xcode error is:

```
Testing Failure - Internal error: unable to find current value '1 of 152' in possible values
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You are using it correctly, but the `adjust(toPickerWheelValue:)` method is buggy, as discussed here: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/16104

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Oletha this seems to remain an unfixed bug in the framework.
We could fix the issue at least temporarily by calling

```
pickerWheel.swipeDown()
```

before calling

```
pickerWheel.adjust(toPickerWheelValue: "Value")
```

Otherwise we received the same crash.

Answer (score 0):

After you displayed picker wheel on screen, you can update the value by:

```
app.pickerWheels.element.adjustToPickerWheelValue("Updated row value")
```